# Adding an Array to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Well hi there! I am making a game called DoorElementals, and I want to do this:

```
ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
public Door(Color... colors) {
  this.colors.add(colors);
}
public void addColor(Color... c){
  this.colors.add(c);
}
```

But `colors` is an array while `this.colors` is an `ArrayList`.
How should I go about this?

Comment: If you want to add an array of `Color` to the `ArrayList` change it like `ArrayList<Color[]> colors = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Have you tried `addAll(Arrays.asList(colors))`?

Comment: a simple `for (Color c : colors) {this.colors.add(c);}` works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT USE `Arrays.asList`. Depending on the amount of calls you do, it will impact the performance, since everytime you call the `asList` method, a new `List` is created.

You can, and should, use:

```
public Door(Color... colors) {
  addAll(colors);
}

public void addAll(Color... colors) {
  for (Color color : colors) {
    myList.add(color);
  }
}
```

Comment: Being me, I didn't remember that you can call methods inside of a constructor. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `java.util.Arrays` class provides a method to convert from an array to a `List`.

```java
ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
public Door(Color... colors) {
   this.colors.addAll(Arrays.asList(colors));
}
public void addColor(Color... c){
   this.colors.addAll(Arrays.asList(c));
}
```

A better practice would be to make your constructor take a `Collection` instead of a using the varargs.

```java
List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
public Door(Collection<Color> colors) {
   this.colors.addAll(colors);
}
```

Comment: You always have this dualism in Java: array world vs collection world. I don't think it really matters who deals with this. The library provides functions to do the trick. So probably, unless there are optimization reasons to implement both versions, it's just easier to only implement the best one, and let the user convert if he needs it. This has the advantage of implicitly pushing the user use to use the fast version whenever he can.

Comment: Sure varargs are cool, but that doesn't make using them a good practice.